# Twitter4j issue with getting tweets from specific day or time period

Tags: java, twitter4j

I want to get tweets from a specific day. using the `setSince()` and `setUntil()` methods, I can get all the tweets from 0:00 - 23:59 but only in UTC.

How can I get tweets from 0:00 - 23:59 in a different time zone?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert time into UTC. That is get the time required in required time zone and convert it into UTC time. Use this UTC time for your query. This way you can get time for any time zone. For converting time into different time zone you can have a look at: **Java.util.Timezone** and **java.util.Date**
Following is a good link which explains how to use it:

[Java convert Data and Time between Timezone](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/)